# How to remove duplicate characters that repeats many times at the end of a string in C language?

Tags: c, string, character, non-repetitive

I am trying to learn how to work with strings in C and I have this problem, I need to reverse a string and print it without any repetitive characters. I have tried the code below and it worked but if I add many repetitive characters of the same type it does not work.

For example: **dodon - nodod - nod** but with the string **dodoneeee - eeeenodod - eenod**. The **e** is still repeated.

The code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
char word[20];
char reverse_string[20];
printf("type a string: ");
scanf("\n%s", word);       
for(int i = strlen(word)-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    // 5 - 5 = 0
    // 5- 4 = 1
    // 5- 3 = 2
    // 5- 2 = 3
    // 5- 1 = 4
    // 5- 0 = 5
    reverse_string[(strlen(word)-1)-i] = word[i];         
  }
  printf("%s\n",reverse_string);     
 for(int i = 0; i< strlen(reverse_string)-1;i++)
 {
    for(int j = i+1; reverse_string[j] != '\0';j++)
    {
        if(reverse_string[j] == reverse_string[i])
        {
            for(int k = j; reverse_string[k] != '\0'; k++)
            {
                //printf("%c\n", reverse_string[k+1]);
                reverse_string[k] = reverse_string[k + 1];
            }                
        }           
    }        
  }
   printf("%s\n", reverse_string);    
return 0;
}
```

Comment: you've got it backwards. *when* reversing the string, check if the character is already in the reversed, and if it is, don't add it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code.
The main problem was the j++. You must stay in the same j until reverse_string[j] != reverse_string[i].
The second problem was that you did not terminated the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char word[20];
char reverse_string[20];
printf("type a string: ");
scanf("%s", word);

for(int i = strlen(word)-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    // 5 - 5 = 0
    // 5- 4 = 1
    // 5- 3 = 2
    // 5- 2 = 3
    // 5- 1 = 4
    // 5- 0 = 5
    reverse_string[(strlen(word)-1)-i] = word[i];
  }
  reverse_string[strlen(word)] = '\0'; //add string termination
  printf("%s\n",reverse_string);


 for(int i = 0; i< strlen(reverse_string)-1;i++)
 {
    for(int j = i+1; reverse_string[j] != '\0';) //j++ was moved. 
    {
        if(reverse_string[j] == reverse_string[i])
        {

            for(int k = j; reverse_string[k] != '\0'; k++)
            {
                //printf("%c\n", reverse_string[k+1]);
                reverse_string[k] = reverse_string[k + 1];
            }

        }
        else
            j++; //j++ was moved here 
    }
  }
   printf("%s\n", reverse_string);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In below line, k will stay at end to same character twice. if k is 4 and end is 5 both 4th and 5th characters will be same. One problem is when k is at null character, k + 1 will overwrite null character.

```
 reverse_string[k] = reverse_string[k + 1];
```